# BigQuery first record of a specific column

Tags: google-bigquery

here's a sample of my output:

[image]

I need to take just the first record per each visitId (with the min time).

I've tried to use the MIN function excluding the hits.time from the GROUP BY list:

> `SELECT STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(date, '%U') AS WK, visitId, date AS SALES_DATE, hits.eventInfo.eventLabel AS SEARCH_DD, year(date) as yr, MIN(hits.time) AS t
>   FROM
>   (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([67977396.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2015-03-04'), TIMESTAMP('2015-03-04')))
>   WHERE hits.eventInfo.eventAction='Depart date' AND hits.eventInfo.eventCategory='Book a train'
>   GROUP BY 
>   1, 2, 3, 4, 5
>   ORDER BY visitId`

and I got this output:

[image]

The problem is that as you can see in the last two records I still have two rows for the same visitId. That's because the query works only with the same search_dd. I need to take the minimum time per each visitId without looking at the search_dd.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is way much easier than you have though. Pay attention to the documentation.

hits.time =     The number of milliseconds after the visitStartTime when this hit was registered. **The first hit will have a hits.time of 0**

So you just have to query for `hits.time=0`,

otherwise to get the first or last record in a WORM (append-only) technology, you need to use something like:

This returns the LAST record for each visitId.

```
SELECT *
   FROM
     (SELECT visitId,hits.time,
             row_number() over (partition BY visitId
                                ORDER BY hits.time desc) seqnum
       FROM [google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910]
    )
   WHERE seqnum=1 
limit 100
```

You can choose to have the Nth value by using seqnum=N.

Also be aware that for a completely unique visit id, you should use a combination of fullVisitorId and visitId. You have more info in the [cookbook](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't want to take the hit happened at hits.time=0 per each visitId. I need to take the hit happened at the first hits.time per each visitId without looking at the search_dd.

Comment: Then you can use the sequence I answered, order by ASC and filter with seqnum=2 .

Answer (score 0):

For a more concise solution, you can do:

```sql
select * 
from [google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910]
where true 
qualify row_number() over (partition BY visitId ORDER BY hits.time desc) = 1
```